# How it is possible that some pages of an HTTPS website like GitHub are marked as censored in China by GreatFire Analyzer but others not?

Tags: https

I believed that China could only either censor the entire domain, or nothing, since HTTPS hides the path part of the URL.

But how it is possible then that e.g. GreatFire Analyzer marks:

- https://en.greatfire.org/github.com as unblocked
- https://en.greatfire.org/github.com/getlantern as blocked

Are they testing mechanisms such as censored browser forks?

Answer (score 0):

GreatFire replied to me at https://twitter.com/GreatFireChina/status/1310515013220667392 , it seems that those censored URLs are redirects to https://raw.githubusercontent.com which is in another domain, and therefore can be censored separately, and is.